# Neo4J: How to hide a specific node in the graph visualisation?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, visualization

I have currently visualised a graph between myself and a number of other people.

**My Current query is:**

```
MATCH (p)-[:emailed]->(m) 
WITH p,count(m) as rels, collect(m) as Contact
WHERE rels > 2  
RETURN p,Contact, rels
```

It creates a pretty complex graph as per image below:

[Messy Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gNSp.png)

You can manually remove them by directly clicking on them as per below:

[Manually hide node from visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndTEg.png)

Which then results in a very different looking graph.

**Q. How do I change my query to automatically show the graph visualisation without showing the nodes that I wish to remove? (i.e by editing the query, so I dont have to manually remove each one)**

By doing either

A) Adding a list of the specific Node ID's in the query to ignore, OR

B) (Ideally) Exclude all nodes that meet a criteria against the node Property

In this case: Ignore [Slug: "myname" ] where includes 'myname'

```
MATCH (p)-[:emailed]->(m) 
WITH p,count(m) as rels, collect(m) as Contact
WHERE rels > 2 AND NOT WHERE p.slug Contains 'Mahdi'  
RETURN p,Contact, rels
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: AND NOT p.slug Contains 'Mahdi'  looks better

Comment: also look for the switch 'auto complete graph' or something like that in the bottom right corner of the neo4j browser

Answer (score 2):

I would change it slightly.  If you collect the actual `:emailed` relationships rather than just counting the node they are connect to you can use them in your result set. Then if you turn off `autocomplete` as JeromeB suggests above then you will actually see some relationship. If you turn off `autocomplete` in your current query there will only be nodes and no relationships which I don't think you are after (unless of course you are).

You could also check to make sure that the `p.slug` attribute exists when testing for CONTAINS otherwise if the attribute does not exist you will not generate any results for that row.

```
MATCH (p:User)-[r:emailed]->(m:User) 
WITH p, COLLECT(r) as rels, COLLECT(m) as contact
WHERE (NOT p.slug CONTAINS 'Mahdi' OR NOT EXISTS(p.slug)) 
  AND size(rels) > 2 
RETURN p, contact, rels
```

I would also add a label to the nodes in the match and an index on the `slug` property.

Comment: Thanks @Jerome-B & Dave for the input.

When using the 'connect result nodes' options, all relationships seem to disappear, but that isn't the case with the above solution.

Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 2):

The autocomplete is 'Connect result nodes' in the Gear tab.